# 41 / 100.0 result has different from 41 * 0.01

Tags: java

Both were hoping for a 0.41 result, but the result was not what I expected. I know this result is a floating point difference. Is there a way to always get the expected result without worrying about doing this kind of floating point arithmetic in Java?

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(41 / 100.0);
            System.out.println(41 * 0.01);
        }
    }
```

Printed output:

```
0.41
0.41000000000000003
```

Comment: You can always use BigDecimal

Comment: In short - as soon as you perform calculations on floating point types, you need to know how they are defined. They are not very intuitive and come with lots of pitfalls, and this is not really specific to the Java language.

Comment: @Szprota21 gives the right suggestion. `BigDecimal.valueOf(41).multiply(new BigDecimal("0.01"))` prints as `0.41`.